# Mylyn refuses to work

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

As shown in this screenshot, I have created a Task in Mylyn, and have activated it, but nevertheless I am unable to enable the task-focused UI: as you can see, the "bubble" button in the package explorer to the left is grayed out. This is the same for all other views that should normally support task focusing. As a consequence, all views behave as if Mylyn was not at all enabled. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I had a certain feature not installed, the "Mylyn Task-Focused Interface". I am not sure why this one is optional, but apparently it is.

Comment: Seven years later; I have just run into the same issue, and it seems I additionally needed the "Mylyn Context Connector: Eclipse IDE".